# Why do we feel headache after ice cold drink?

Tags: human-biology

Whenever we drink ice cold drinks, after a couple of seconds, suddenly we feel intense pain rising from upper nose to forehead. What is reason behind this pain after too cold drink and why it's felt in that particular part of head?

Comment: This is called **sphenopalatine ganglioneuralgia**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream_headache

Answer (score -2):

The cold drink causes the blood in blood vessels of gums to freeze. This stimulates nerve endings and causes a sensation in brain.